# On-Premise Team Foundation Server missing create new project link

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

We have updated our On-Premise Team Foundation Server to 2015. A couple of year ago, I had created Default Team Project, but I forgot how I created it.

In TFS 2015, I could not find ***New*** link next to ***Browse*** which we normally see in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online).

[image]

Our server administrator said I have Administrator access. Could you point me to the right direction?

[image]

### [Screen Shot for CeCe's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36882465/296861)

I could not see **New team project** link.

[image]

### [Screen Shot for Patrick's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36882030/296861)

I could not see **New team project** link.

[image]

### TFS Version

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to collection administration page, you'll see "New team project":

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. I do not see New team project link. Please see my updated screenshot.

Comment: Only TFS 2015 Update 2 or later supports creating a team project from the web. Otherwise, you need to create team projects in Team Explorer. If you want to create team projects from web, please upgrade your TFS to the Update2.

Answer (score 3):

> If you're using **TFS 2015 Update 2 or later** then you can create a
>   team project from the web as well.

More detail info please refer the link from MSDN: [Create a team project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/overview/create-team-project)

So for your TFS version, you should either update it to TFS 2015 update 2 or you may have to create team project through Team explorer.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this feature is only available in TFS 2015 **Update 2** and beyond.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I do not see New team project link. Please see my updated screenshot.

Comment: @Win Create a team project through TFS web portal is only support for TFS 2015 Update2 or later. More details, please see my updated answer.